# Sin acceso a internet al conectarme a hotspot windows 10

Tags: windows10, redes

Quiero consultarles, tengo un mini portatil que utilizo para crear un *hotspot* con este link:

> https://es.gizmodo.com/como-convertir-un-equipo-con-windows-10-en-un-hotspot-q-1724793991

Lo creo correctamente, el inconveniente viene en el equipo que se va a conectar a este, me aparece conectividad *Sin acceso a internet*.

El adaptador virtual donde creo el *hotspot* me muestra esta información en cmd con *ipconfig*:

```
Direccion IPV4 169.254.233.101
Mascara de red 255.255.0.0
```

En el equipo que conecto me muestra esto:

```
Direccion IPV4 169.254.79.116
Mascara de red 255.255.0.0
```

Que puedo hacer?
Ambos equipos *hotspot* y conectado son **Windows 10**.